# Using Ntrights.exe to grant user rights fails to _Enable_ the rights

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2019

When using `Ntrights.exe` to grant permission to a privilege, I do not see any ability to Enable said privileges.  Is this supposed to be automatic?

Example:

`ntrights.exe +r SeShutdownPrivilege -u %username%` will add this privilege to my user, but when I check the state using `whoami /priv` I still show the "State" to be Disabled.

Is there a `sysinternals` option or something along this line which will also *ENABLE* a user's permissions?

Comment: Are you issuing this command from an elevated CMD and from an administrator login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you issuing this command from an elevated CMD and from
an administrator login that is not `username`?

The shutdown permission cannot be granted to yourself, unless you
already have it, and then it a "no operation".

You need, as said above, login as administrator,
run CMD as Administrator, and then issue the `ntrights` command.

You may need to reboot after running the `ntrights` command, and additionally, if you have pushed any GPO to the unit, it could reset this privilege/right, so you should run `ntrights` explicitly after the GPO has been pushed.

Comment: User account logged in is an administrator, CMD is ran as an admin (actually called from a batch file).  It gives a successful completion, but I'm not seeing the behavior expected/hoped for.  Was hoping that using Alt+F4 after the fact would no longer log me out, but would give the shutdown/restart menu as it does in Windows 10 by default.  If there's a way to do this via Batch file, this would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Have you rebooted afterward ?

Comment: You sir, are a genius.  This was part of the issue.  Also, I believe the other half, is I mistakenly pushed a GPO after initially setting the rights - I tested again using just `ntrights` and then rebooting, and this solved it - the GPO has this privilege disabled.

Comment: Added the bit about rebooting and GPO that could cause hiccups to the answer and marked accepted.

Answer (score 0):

> When using Ntrights.exe to grant permission to a privilege, I do not see any ability to Enable said privileges. Is this supposed to be automatic?

No, for most privileges it's supposed to be explicitly done by the process that's performing the task, by using [Adjust­Token­Privileges()](https://winterdom.com/dev/security/tokens/) before it does the actual system call. As long as the privilege is *present* in the process's token, the process can enable/disable it at any time it wants – it doesn't need an additional grant for that.

It's one of those OpenVMS quirks that WinNT inherited, and it's meant to make privilege use more explicit (and more auditable). Take SeBackupPrivilege for example, which lets admins to read any file bypassing all ACLs – Windows has the ability to record all its uses to the security (audit) log, so if the privilege were always active, the log would be full of accidental "user A used privileges to bypass ACLs without even realizing it" events.

(Similarly, on Linux you also generally don't run with CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE always on, but deliberately switch to the "root" account which has that privilege; the account-switch is what gets logged although each individual ACL-bypass is not.)

Comment: Thanks - I have seen the references to `AdjustTokenPrivileges()` in other articles, but I am not certain if there's a way to manipulate this solely with Batch/CMD processing.  Is it possible?  Would it be possible to do this with Powershell natively?  The only reason I'm doing it is to build into processes for Server to allow the main admin user access the shutdown menu when using `Alt+F4` instead of just logging out, but am wishing to do this in an automated fashion, as I'm using it to standardize image builds.  Windows 10 does this natively as documented.

Comment: There are PowerShell modules for that, yes (e.g. `PSPrivilege` in PSGallery); anything you can do via Win32 can be done through P/Invoke (you can write inline C# using `Add-Type`). Keep in mind though that it's per-process, not per-user; it's possible to edit the token of a different process, but by default you'd be affecting only PowerShell itself. (As a side note internally PowerShell itself also has code to enable SeRestorePrivilege when you're trying to delete something that you normally don't have the 'delete' permission for.)